# Accessing button in title bar only in one activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-tabhost, titlebar

I have a custom title bar and a `TabHost` layout that I'm using. The `TabHost` has 4 tabs with different activities. I added an `ImageButton` to the title bar, but I only want it active in one of those for activities. Could someone please tell me how to do that?

Also, is it ok if I define the button in the titlebar xml?

Answer (score 1):

One way that comes to mind is to set listeners to the tab buttons so you always know what tab you're in. If its the right one, you setVisibility(0) on that button, else setVisibility(8).
There might be simpler ways to do it though.

Comment: this might not be the most optimal method, but it sure works!

Comment: I have nothing here right now, check this: http://www.androidadb.com/class/android/widget/TabHost/OnTabChangeListener.java.html
You can listen if that one special Tab is hit, then set the visibility on the button.

Answer (score 1):

```
myTabHost.setOnTabChangedListener(new OnTabChangeListener() {
  @Override
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
    if (tabId =="yourTabId") {
      yourButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
    else
    {
        yourButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: That's amazing :) Thanks!! Could you also please tell me how to make the button call a method in the tab I want it to be shown for? Currently it calls a method in the Main Activity where the tab is initialised. The purpose of the button is to switch between two views in that second activity.

Comment: You're absolutely welcome :-} But could you add some code so I can have an idea of the sequence of events that need to happen?

Comment: So essentially I have a ViewSwitcher with a ListView and a MapView inside it (the MapView hidden). On the press of the button, the listview should hide (with some transition maybe) and the map should show. Also, I want to change the button image depending on which of the two views is on display.